# Understanding asynchronous and synchronous in digital design

Tags: digital-logic

Where's a good place to start in find any resources in understanding exactly how asynchronous and synchronous works in digital design?

Comment: The Art of Electronics (Horowiz and Hill, Cambridge University press, ISBN 0-521-37095-7) chapter 8 Digital Electronics discusses Combinational Logic ("asynchronous") and Sequential Logic ("synchronous"); good place to start if you're building breadboard circuits from the discrete transistor level, with emphasis on analog circuit fundamentals.

Comment: Another approach is Verilog for Digital Design (Vahid and Lysecky, 2007, Wiley press, ISBN 978-0-470-05262-4), which skips the underlying hardware considerations and focuses on the Verilog Hardware Description Language; covers combinational logic gates, synchronous logic, finite state machines, best practices. Good place to start if you're working with FPGA hardware instead of a breadboard.

Comment: Note that even when something is clocked (such as a D flip flop) a design may still not be synchronous. Look up *ripple counter* for an example.

Comment: Basically a shopping question... you know the drill...